# Webify embedded linux-based controller through cellular network

Tags: linux, networking, embedded, cellular-network

Need a basic direction in the following project.

There is a linux based controller doing some industrial control stuff.
The box is equipped with cellular modem and is capable to get online through cellular carrier. Cellular communication is used because controller is mostly installed where no cables or short range radio is available. Places where sun don't normally shine :)

The task is to allow internet clients to connect directly to the box for some basic control/monitoring stuff. The problem is connectivity - how clients will discover the box? - I'd like to have the box act as a server (if possible). Assuming that cellular carrier allows the box to get online doesn't necessarily mean that the box will get public IP so that anyone would be able to get connected. To my understanding the cellular network acts as a gateway from those who are working inside of it, and reaching someone in that network from outside isn't possible. Am I wrong? We are looking for a generic solution, not a solution around particular cellular provider. The controller is installed in different countries, we need to find the **standard way** to "webify" it.

The software (and hardware) in the box is ours, we can basically do anything, but I am looking for the **right** way to do it in order to avoid surprises with different providers later. BTW, the solution doesn't necessarily have to be technical, may be it's possible to buy a permanent IP's per box, or setup VPNs.. Which way should I dig to? What questions to ask?

Your ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your summary of the problem is basically correct. I've implemented several systems that do this, and the odds of success are good.

The way you tackle this will depend on the number of remote units you expect a single user to interact with. If each user will handle only one or two devices, it's plausible to implement the web server on the remote device. If each user handles many devices, consider centralising as much administration as possible. I've implemented this using [Zenoss](http://community.zenoss.org/) for data logging, and a custom control server.

If the web server sits on the remote device, you can either buy a SIM with a static IP, or use a proxy server. I recommend setting up a proxy server unless the number of devices is very small.

There are three options for SIMs:

- Static IP with an address on the public Internet will be expensive, and negotiating the deal with each provider in each country will be irksome. No proxy server is required.
- Private APN SIMs will give you the option of a static address, but in a private address range. Negotiation with the mobile network is still required, and you will require a proxy server to sit between the public Internet and the private address range,
- Standard data SIMs will connect to the Internet through NAT. You can use these to host your service by opening a VPN connection (we used openvpn) to your server. You can now reach the devices directly by connecting to the same VPN, or through a proxy server.

If you use openvpn, here are some more tips:

- Give each unit a public serial number, and a private key. Store these in the firmware of the unit, and in a central database. Put the public serial number on the outside of the unit. You can use an openvpn login script to ensure that a particular unit always appears at the correct IP address, which keeps the proxy configuration static.
- You can control openvpn's bandwidth usage by adjusting its keepalive behaviour, and how often it renegotiates. Measure and tune this before a large deployment.
- The NAT timeouts in the mobile networks are generally between 5 and 15 minutes. The device must send a packet to the server often enough to keep NAT alive.
- Cheap SIM deals may be web only with limited ports.

Other tips:

- GPRS modem firmware can (rarely) crash internally. If your hardware supports it, provide software with the ability to power cycle the modem.
- Test your box in areas with poor coverage in your own country before you send out international shipments.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian, this is a very comprehensive feedback

Comment: Another option might be a relay service like https://yaler.net/ (disclosure: I'm a founder) which also allows you to use standard SIM cards.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem with "mobile agent" appearing in different places or using different providers (in this case just one provider, but it's almost the same). Usually it's solved using some kind of home agent - a server that the mobile connects to and gives details about how to reach it or if it can't be reached directly then the home agent acts as a proxy.

Client always contact the home agent first and then if it is possible they contact the mobile or if it's not they use the server as a proxy.

In some cases dynamic dns might be sufficient in other you need real proxy/ façade.

There's a good book: Andrew S. Tanenbaum & Maarten van Steen :"Distributed Systems: Principles and Paradigms"

Comment: Proxi makes sense and would probably be the most reliable approach. Can such proxy be installed on some VPS and bridge between two parties? Are there any proxies off the shelves or this is something proprietary made? Basically we'd want request stream from clients delegated to the controller and responses from controller delegated back to the caller. Since there are many-to-many relations (many clients to many boxes) I don't see how this differentiation is made? How would proxy know which box I am trying to converse with?

Comment: You will of course need an addressing or numbering scheme.  Could be as simple as a serial number in each device, with your server doing translation to customer friendly names or installation numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask cellular provider to give you a SIM card with internet access and fixed IP address. Then you can host any server you like. Do not forget that you are dealing with limited bandwidth.